# Returning to Commited Detached Head (GIT)

Tags: git

So I was on a detached head and I commited some changes. I am now on a different head, how do I return to my detached head change that thread to the master?

Thanks

```
$ git commit -m "Connect Users to Fitbit accounts"
[detached HEAD b3b8249] Connect Users to Fitbit accounts
17 files changed, 159 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `git checkout` the commit:

```
git checkout b3b8249
```

Branches are basically a named commit and `git checkout` works with everything that can be resolved to a commit (Commits, Branches, Tags, [the reflog](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html)), not only with branches.

---

As I mentioned the reflog: In case you don't remember the exakt commit hash the reflog is the way to go:

```
[root@/tmp/test (5d0f65b...)]git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
[root@/tmp/test master]touch b
[root@/tmp/test master]git add b
[root@/tmp/test master]git commit -m "Add b"
[master 9bf5987] Add b
 0 files changed
 create mode 100644 b
[root@/tmp/test master]git reflog
9bf5987 HEAD@{0}: commit: Add b
5d0f65b HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from 5d0f65ba749c8f39773c4edb16ab40c5c58501d4 to master
```

The first column will tell you where the HEAD pointed at and you can retrieve the older state by passing `HEAD@{N}` to `git checkout`:

```
[root@/tmp/test master]git checkout HEAD@{1}
Note: checking out 'HEAD@{1}'.

...

HEAD is now at 5d0f65b... Add a
```

The reflog will save your head in certain situations as it allows you to retrieve almost anything that was lost, e.g. commits lost in a rebase, commits lost in a reset etc.

Comment: You can also give reflog-only or ID-only commits a name (branch or tag name) with, e.g., `git branch new-branch 5d0f65b` or `git tag temporary-tag 5d0f65b`.  A name like `HEAD@{1}` is just another way to write the SHA-1 of the commit, so this also works with those: `git branch new-branch HEAD@{1}`, for instance.